# Multiple separate amp-lightbox-gallery in a page

Tags: amp-html

How can I have multiple separate lightbox galleries in a page?

Documentations does not mention a thing about this.

I know there is a lightbox component, that can be used to separate some image sets, but that lacks some features like thumbnails and captions.

Googling does not help, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: easy to do; just give them separate IDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `lightbox` attribute to a different value, you can make them part of different galleries.

From the [amp-lightbox-gallery
 example](https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-lightbox-gallery/) (emphasis mine):

> By default, all lightboxed elements will be grouped into the same lightbox unless they belong to a carousel. All elements in the same lightboxed carousel belong to the same lightbox. **You can override this behavior by setting the lightbox attribute to a unique string.**

Example:

```
<div>
  <amp-img lightbox="example" src="image1.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
  <amp-img lightbox="example" src="image2.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
</div>

<!-- These will belong to a different lightbox gallery -->
<div>
  <amp-img lightbox="another" src="image3.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
  <amp-img lightbox="another" src="image4.jpg" width="400" height="300" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
</div>
```

Comment: I really don't know how I could miss that! Thanks.